# Як правильніше: «Кам'яна доба» чи «кам'яний вік», чи обидва однаково?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Шукаю канонічний переклад терміну «Stone Age» (а також аналогічних термінів “Iron Age”, “Bronze Age”, “Golden Age” і т.д.).

Відповідні сторінки україномовної Вікіпедії мають назви «[кам'яна **доба**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0)», «[залізна **доба**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0)», «[бронзова **доба**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0)», «[золота **доба**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0)».

Проте наступні форми виявляються досить поширеними: «кам'яний **вік**», «залізний **вік**», «бронзовий **вік**», «золотий **вік**». Судячи з результатів пошуку в Google, вони виявляються більш поширеними, ніж варіант з «добою».

У «*Словнику української мови в 11 томах*» зустрічаються «[кам'яний вік», «кам'яна доба](http://sum.in.ua/s/kam.janyj)», «[бронзовий вік](http://sum.in.ua/s/bronzovyj)», «[золотий вік](http://sum.in.ua/s/zolotyj)» але не інші вищезгадані терміни.

Чи є еквівалентними за правильністю ці два варіанти (доба / вік)? Або є причина віддавати перевагу одному перед іншим, загалом чи в певних контекстах? Спасибі заздалегідь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В українській мові слово [**ВІК**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA) вживають, насамперед, щодо тривалості життя будь-якого живого організму, як то людини, тварини, рослини та іншого біологічного різноманіття. Зважаючи на семантичний зміст слова [**ВІК**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vik), ним можуть позначатися й інші лексичні одиниці.

**Доба** - це визначений обмежений термін часу, який може вимірюватися в годинах (24 години це одна доба), днях (сім днів це один тиждень), місяцях (12 місяців це один рік), роках (100 років це одне століття), століттях (Епоха Відродження), тисячоліттях (Нова ера), десятках тисяч років (Палеоліт), мільйонах років (Мезозой).

**Велика Українська Енциклопедія** надає таке визначення:

> **[Кам’яна доба](https://vue.gov.ua/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%E2%80%99%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0)** - найтриваліший доісторичний період часу, впродовж якого люди широко використовували камінь для виготовлення знарядь
> праці.

А електронний ресурс **Національної Академії Наук України** містить добірку наукових праць [**Кам’яна доба України**](https://www.nas.gov.ua/UA/Book/Pages/default.aspx?BookID=0000013736).

То ж, сказати "**кам'яний вік**" чи "**кам'яна ера**" або "**кам'яна епоха**" не буде помилкою і буде зрозумілим, але якщо вас цікавить саме органічне звучання з науковою точністю, то краще сказати "**кам'яна доба**".